# Est-ce que les majuscules portent des accents?

Tags: diacritiques, majuscules

Par exemple si une phrase commence par le mot "écrire" faut il mettre le "é" en majuscule sans accent ou avec accent?

> Écrire à ma femme.

ou

> Ecrire à ma femme.

Comment: La réponse courte : les majuscules doivent être accentuées, mais nombreux sont ceux qui ne savent pas le faire sur un clavier, d'où les fautes communes. Voir la question citée par @Toto pour plus de détails.

Comment: un petit article sur le sujet 
https://www.druide.com/enquetes/faut-il-accentuer-les-majuscules-et-les-capitales